# How does the potato cannon work?

Tags: surviv.io

So I was using potato cannon in surviv.io (I had 2!!), but I was unsure how to use it (8 kills anyway, they're OP).

I know that:
1. The cannon slows you down a lot when held

2. it has infinite ammo
3. it has 4 shot capacity
4. the projectiles explode.

However I don't know how far the projectiles travel. Sometimes the pass over obstacles, sometimes they hit and explode, sometimes they act like USAS, and sometimes they whizz past my mouse and miss. Does anyone know what the Potato Cannon mechanics are?

Comment: Can you make a list of which obstacles make it act a certain way; i.e hogheads make it act like USAS, etc.

Comment: It might depend on the obstacle, which is why I am asking.